# change attribute of a svg in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have svg element loos like this where I took from google browser developer tool

[image: took from google browser developer tool].

```
<svg>
  <g transform="translate(250,260) rotate(-90 0 0)">
    //......
  </g>
/svg>
```

SVG looks like this. I want to change the translate to (300,300)

I tried like this ,

```
svg.children[0].attributes("transform", "translate(" + 100 / 2 + "," + (100 / 2 + 10) + ") rotate(-90 0 0)");
```

but it gives attributes is not a function error. How may I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element.attributes` is just a collection of all attributes registered to the element. To set an attribute use `Element.setAttribute`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Example: `svg.children[0].setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + 100 / 2 + "," + (100 / 2 + 10) + ") rotate(-90 0 0)");`

Answer (score 0):

`.attributes` does not accept parameters, but returns a `NamedNodeMap` which is a live collection of attribute nodes registered at the element. You can set the property directly following using `document.querySelector()`, `Element.querySelector()`

```js
document.querySelector("svg")
.querySelector("g")
.transform = "translate(" 
             + 100 / 2 + "," 
             + (100 / 2 + 10) + ") rotate(-90 0 0)";
```

```html
<svg>
  <g transform="translate(250,260) rotate(-90 0 0)">
  </g>
</svg>
```